# How to expand Text in swiftui to take entire space

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a Screen that has a couple of components including a Text component.

Here I want the text component to take entire available space ( with `maxWidht` and `MaxHeight` extend the height and do not expand.)

here is code block

```swift
VStack {
    Spacer()
    Text("Loading diagnostic\n")
    Spacer()
    LottieView(loopMode: .loop)
        .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
        .padding(.vertical, 15)
    Text("Commands pending \(diagnoseViewModel.numberOfCommandsPending)")
    Spacer()
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.background(Color.red)
```

[image]

I want here the whole red part to be in the center.

here is full code

```swift
ScrollView {
    //MARK -Please make this zstack take entire visiblae space height
    ZStack {
        VStack(spacing:0) {
            HStack{
                Image("Diagnostic")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 23, height: 23)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(ViewControllerCosntants.secondaryColor700))
                Text("Diagnosis")
                    .font(.custom(ViewControllerCosntants.robotoRegular, size: 26))
                    .foregroundColor(Color(ViewControllerCosntants.secondaryColor700))
                    .padding(.leading, 16)
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50, alignment: .leading)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 25, bottom: 15, trailing: 25))

            IconButton(iconName: "Share", title: "Share", description: $description)
                .padding(.bottom, 28)
                .onTapGesture {
                    ShareDiagnostic()
                }

            Divider()
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 3)
                .overlay(Color("PrimaryColor"))
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 25, bottom: 0, trailing: 25))

            if(loading) {
                VStack{
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Loading diagnostic\n")
                    Spacer()
                    LottieView(loopMode: .loop)
                        .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                        .padding(.vertical, 15)
                    Text("Commands pending \(diagnoseViewModel.numberOfCommandsPending)")
                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(Color.red)
            } else {
                Text("The multi line text goes here.")
            }
        }
        .disabled(diagnoseViewModel.showLoading)
    }
}
.background(Color("Body"))
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

The app supports minimum of ios14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try showing the panel with the red background as an overlay over the `ScrollView`:

```swift
ScrollView{
    // Other content as before
}
.overlay {
    if loading {
        VStack{
            // Contents with LottieView, as before
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}
.background(Color("Body"))
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
```

[image: Red]

---

*EDIT* For iOS 14, you need to use the (now deprecated) [`overlay(_:alignment:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/overlay(_:alignment:)) modifier. I would suggest moving the conditional `VStack` to a separate computed property with `@ViewBuilder` attribute:

```swift
@ViewBuilder
private var fullPageInfo: some View {
    if loading {
        VStack{
            // Contents with LottieView, as before
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Then it's used like this:

```swift
ScrollView{
    // Other content as before
}
.overlay(fullPageInfo)
```

Comment: my app supports a minimum of ios14, it seems overlay is only available in ios15+. Sorry about confusion

Comment: `overlay` is available in iOS 14 -- you just have to use `overlay()` and not `overlay { }`. With this solution, you could just do `overlay(Group { ... })` and include the contents in this answer.

Comment: @RonWeasley Answer updated with alternative version compatible with iOS 14.